# Get html from list of pages

Tags: android, html, http, jsoup

I have list of web pages(over 100) with I have to vistit and collect data from.
I decided to save the html from all of them to one file, and then use Jsoup to find the interesting data.

But problem is to I do not know how to run 100 threads, and save the responses into one file, any ideas?

Comment: You should read about `AsyncTask`, but I wouldn't run a hundred of them concurrently.

Answer (score 0):

maybe it's not a masterpiece, but it works, and I wanted to make it as simple as possible.

```
ArrayList<String> links = new ArrayList<>();
Elements myDiv;

private void saveDetails() throws IOException {
    if(repeat < links.size()){
        repeat++;
        textView.setText(String.valueOf(repeat));
        saveFile(myDiv.toString());
        myDiv = null;
        getDetails(links.get(repeat));
    }else {
        textView.setText("finished");
    }
}

private void getDetails(String urlStr) {
    final String detailsUrl = urlStr;
    new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Message msg = Message.obtain();
            try {
                Document doc = Jsoup.connect(detailsUrl).get();
                myDiv = doc.select(".exhibitor-contact");
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            detailsHandler.sendMessage(msg);
        }
    }.start();
}
private Handler detailsHandler = new Handler() {
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        super.handleMessage(msg);
        try {
            saveDetails();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to save all of them in a file and then process them. You can gather information one by one. It is my suggestion:

```
arrayList urls = {100 site-url}; //in correct syntax
Document doc = null;
for (String url : urls) {
    doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
    //now proccess doc.toString as you want(in regular expression for example)
    //save your desired information
}
```